# Is it possible to make Eclipse's code-folding gutter black?

Tags: eclipse, colors

Is there a way (I'll settle for a hack) to make the code-folding gutter in Eclipse render with a black background? I'm clinging to TextMate as my main editor but would really like to go back to Eclipse for code completion, but I'm stuck with this ugly crap: http://gfx.notbrain.com/eclipse_code_fold_gutter.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gargh, doesn't look like it... this guy has the same issue:

http://blog.codefront.net/2006/09/28/vibrant-ink-textmate-theme-for-eclipse/

**EDIT**: Looks like this has been filed as a bug with Eclipse already, see:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194313

Comment: Actually I did a restart of Eclipse and now the gutter <em>IS</em> black. But now to get rid of the bright white line that separates the gutter from the code! Could definitely be tweaked for better readability, it just feels too cramped. Maybe it's my font size.

http://gfx.notbrain.com/eclipse_code_fold_gutter_black.png

Comment: BTW, I'm using ZendStudio 7 beta, so this may be because of that.

Comment: I've added the details to the bug in Eclipse's bugzilla.... https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194313

Answer (score 23):

After you change the background color of the editor, disable then re-enable code folding and click apply this seems to fix the color problem however keeps that ugly white line separator.

Comment: This works! Simply hit Ctrl + numpad-/ twice and the folding margin comes back in the expected colour.

Comment: If you are in Mac, press cmd+/

Answer (score 11):

I found a nice work around until this is fixed. First disable folding by default (**preferences->C++->Editor->Folding**) for new editors.

Then, whenever you open a new editor the folding 'column' wont be available. Now, open a new editor, Right-click on the far left of the text (the line numbers if they're enabled) and select 'enable folding' (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>).

Then, anything that is to be folded by default will be folded and the folding +'s and -'s will be available on the dark background - no color glitches.

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me as well

Comment: Can't believe this hasn't been fixed! I figured this work around over three years ago now :P

Comment: Thank Haggerty. Note that:   Ctrl + /   (with / locate on numpad key).