# How do I change the background color of the column with the expanders in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, editor, themes

Recently after scorching my retinas from the garish white background in Eclipse, I found some of the excellent posts about how to change the colors so it uses sane (i.e. dark background) colors in the editor.  However, one problem present in all solutions is that background of the column with the expanders for code folding is always white.  Is there a way to change the background of that column?

I'm not the only person that has this problem, as shown in the screenshots for the following questions:

- [Dark Color Scheme for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120621/dark-colorscheme-for-eclipse)
- [Color Themes for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse) (application of color schemes results in this issue on a Mac, no idea about PC)

I know that the problem is not language specific as it happens in Java, Python, HTML, and everything else.  Any hints on where in the pages of preferences this setting is?

Comment: Eclipse sucks when it comes to skinning and themes. Not sure there's any solution to that awful white stripe. I try to avoid Eclipse as much as possible, for the reason I can't get a consistent dark-colour theme. But I'll be watching to see if anyone does post a solution that works...

Comment: Someone came up with a great hack here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5341037/4541374.  Just hit Ctrl+/ twice (using the numpad forward slash) and this will disable and re-enable the gutter.  Great for those of us who still use older versions of Eclipse for whatever application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to [Eclipse Bug 62712](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=62712) which is fixed in build 20090329-2000 almost a year ago. In my Galileo of build 20090920-1017 it just works when I change the background color through *General > Editors > Text Editors*. Here's a screen (don't pay attention to the ugly color combo, my bg defaults to white and I just picked random yellow to demonstrate that the ruler background get changed as well):

[image]

In other words, just upgrade your Eclipse to include this bugfix. Did you check *Help > Check for Updates*?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Rational Team Concert, which has a lot of neat features, but is constantly a revision behind. Guess I'll have to wait for the next release in November.  Until then, you win the correct answer, and I get to rock out to The White Stripe.