# Vertical white line on eclipse

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make Eclipse's code-folding gutter black?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041760/is-it-possible-to-make-eclipses-code-folding-gutter-black)

The white line was invisible on default color scheme but when I applied different color scheme it appeared ..

The white line contains code folding buttons also ..

[image: http://imgur.com/rqdD6]

Comment: Do you want to remove it, or do you want it to be consistent with the color scheme?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1041760/645270)

Comment: I want it to be consistent with every color scheme I use Dark or Light..

Is there a tweak for this..??

PLease help

Comment: Yes, the link I provided does give you a solution for that. They mentioned having trouble with some other vertical line after fixing the collapse-bar though.

Comment: Yes I guess that helped me remove that fat white line ...but still there is a very thin white line present..

Is it ok to be like that ??  I mean does everyone get this line or is it me only thats getting this white line ..??

I am providing image link ....

http://imgur.com/6Ek7F

Comment: No I am okay with it if its normal... :D

But whats GI ..?? !! :o

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks :)

ButI am not gonna search for it anymore now ...

Can you tell me how can I put this post as RESOLVED since my problem has been solved & I don't wanna leave it open now...

Comment: Actually, since you resolved it using another question it should simply be removed for being a duplicate :p Just wait for it. (I posted an answer referring to the other answers now)

Comment: Ohh nice...
I hope you will help me in future as well :)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041760/is-it-possible-to-make-eclipses-code-folding-gutter-black) thread:

> "After you change the background color of the editor, disable then
>   re-enable code folding and click apply this seems to fix the color
>   problem however keeps that ugly white line separator."

or

> "First disable folding by default (preferences->C++->Editor->Folding)
>   for new editors.
>
> Then, whenever you open a new editor the folding 'column' wont be
>   available.
>
> Now, open a new editor, rt-click on the far left of the text (the line
>   numbers if they're enabled) and select 'enable folding' (or press ctrl
>   + numpad-divide).
>
> Then, anything that is to be folded by default will be folded and the
>   folding +'s and -'s will be available on the dark background - no
>   colour glitches".

Comment: This works for Eclipse version 2020-03 (4.15.0). Thanks!